# Topological vector spaces over field with discrete topology

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, topological-rings

I know the following theorem on topological vector spaces.

> **[Theorem]**
>   On every finite dimensional vector space over field $k$, there is a unique topological vector space structure.
>   (The proof is here https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/top-vs-3.pdf)

Let $k=\mathbb{R}$ with discrete topology and $V=\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology.
Both $k$ and $V$ are topological vector spaces over $k$ which have the dimension $\mathrm{dim}_k (k) = \mathrm{dim}_k (V)=1$.

When I apply above theorem to $\mathbb{R}$, I get $k \cong V$ as topological vector space.
Is this correct $??$  Please give me opinions.

Comment: When $k$ is discrete and $V$ isn't, you've likely violated one of the axioms requiring the algebraic operations to be continuous.  So, $V$ is NOT a topological vector space anymore.  A TVS is more than a topological space that is also a vector space.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem you reference assumes the field "k" is either **R** or **C** equipped with the standard topology.  It doesn't say anything about a vector space over **R** with **R** given the discrete topology.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the first line of those notes:

> Throughout this note $\Bbb K$ will be one of the fields $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, equipped with the standard topology. All vector spaces mentioned here are over $\Bbb K$.

So it doesn't apply to the field in the *discrete* topology.

Comment: @EricWofsey so it is. I’ll remove it. Thx.